# Corona SDK: Restart an app only when user press "home"

Tags: lua, coronasdk, onpause

Using corona SDK, i would like a clean restart of my app, everytime the user hits the homebutton.
If he/she receives a phonecall, pulls down the dropdownmenu and so on, I would like for the app to continue in its' current state.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
/S

Comment: I suppose you mean iPhone ?

Comment: Both android(Those with homebutton..) and iPhone. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how i solved it!

```
suspendTime = 0
resumeTime = 0

function onSystemEvent( event )
    if event.type == "applicationSuspend" then
        suspendTime = os.time()
        print(suspendTime)
    elseif event.type == "applicationResume" then
        resumeTime = os.time()
        print(resumeTime)
        print("deltaTime: "..resumeTime - suspendTime )
            if(resumeTime - suspendTime > 30) then
            local sceneName = storyboard.getCurrentSceneName()
            if(sceneName ~= "levels.splash") then
                print(sceneName)
                print(resumeTime)
                        storyboard.gotoScene("levels.splash")
            end
        end
    end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("system", onSystemEvent)
```

Comment: dont forget to suspendTime = 0 and resumeTime = 0, after finding delta ;) by the way, does os.time() returns the hour allways? what does it do when you suspend the app on 23:59 and open that again in 00:01 ?

Comment: I believe that os:time is the unix timestamp.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: So, I guess it doesn't retrun minutes. Anyways you can make sure by trying or manuplating that value. If it works fine allways, no need to do anything..

Answer (score 1):

```
function onKeyEvent( event )
    local keyname = event.keyName;
    if (event.phase == "up" and (event.keyName=="back" or event.keyName=="menu" or event.keyName == "home" )) then
        if keyname == "menu" then
        os.exit()
    end
    end
    return false
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent )
```

This one will work for android. 
I checked from http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/keyName.html, so there is no way to do that in iPhone.

But you can try this : get the time when application is suspended. And save it to documentes directory. Then when application is resume, check the time between two sessions. If there is more then half an hour, restart all things.

Comment: no this does not work for home button on android,as you can see in you link,it says: `homePage` `The "navigate to home page" key (this is not the "Home" button on Android).`  eyeball answer works like charm!